# Add items to an array inside foreach

Tags: php

I want to know how can I add items to end of an array, i've tried a lot, but i can't.

```
$arr = [
    'shopping_cart' => [
        'items' => [
            0 => [
                'item_id' => 22161,
                 'item_price' => 24.99,
                 'item_url' => '',

            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

I tried with this code, but is not working, it's not add the new index, but create new one inside the indexes that already exists.

```
 foreach($arr['shopping_cart']['items'] as $index => &$value) {         


      array_push($value, [$index => 'test']);  

       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($value);
   }

// Result in
Array
  (
    [item_id] => 1
    [item_price] => 24.99
    [item_url] => 
    [0] => Array
     (
        [0] => test
     )

)
// I want to create new index with different data, keeping the index that already exists.


Array
   (
     [item_id] => 1
     [item_price] => 24.99
     [item_url] => 

 )

    Array
  (
    [item_id] => 2
    [item_price] => 34.99
    [item_url] => 

)
```

Can someone explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your desired output. Do you want to add a new index after item_url?

Answer (score 2):

No need to iterate over the array, just add values:

```
$arr['shopping_cart']['items'][] = [
   'item_id' => 22162,
   'item_price' => 34.99,
   'item_url' => '',   
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will help you out. For adding a new data to index.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/803243)

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$arr = [
'shopping_cart' => [
    'items' => [
        0 => [
            'item_id' => 22161,
             'item_price' => 24.99,
             'item_url' => '',

        ],
]]];
$arr['shopping_cart']['items'][]=array(
   'item_id' => 22162,
   'item_price' => 34.99,
   'item_url' => '');

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: It's creating new value inside existing index, i want to create new index with different data. I'll edit my question

Comment: @TomMoore Yes sure go ahead... update your post with expected output.

Comment: @TomMoore try this https://eval.in/803249 I have updatedd my post for that.

Comment: Is working, but there's isn't a way to do this inside foreach?

Comment: @TomMoore If you do it inside for each loop it will create multiple entries, if you loop iterates more than once. Lets say if you have more than one item data.

Comment: Yes, i have more that one, so duplicate this code for 10 items for example, will not be cool.

Answer (score 0):

change `array_push($value, [$index => 'test']);`  to `$value[$index] = 'test' ;`